# Eclipse Scout: form.doOk() does not call ModifyHandler#execStore()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-scout

I am trying to write integration tests for my Eclipse Scout application.

My tests method looks like this:

```
AForm form = new AForm();
form.setPersonId(3L);
form.startNew();
form.doOk();
//assertions on the form.
```

My problem is that the code in `AForm.ModifyHandler#execStore()` the ModifyHandler is not executed. To ensure this I have modified the implementation: I throw an IllegalStateException:

```
public class ModifyHandler extends AbstractFormHandler {

  @Override
  protected void execLoad() throws ProcessingException {
    IAService service = SERVICES.getService(IAService.class);
    AFormData formData = new AFormData();
    exportFormData(formData);
    formData = service.load(formData);
    importFormData(formData);
    setEnabledPermission(new UpdateAPermission());

  }

  @Override
  protected void execStore() throws ProcessingException {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Exception for Unit Test: execStore()");
    // IAService service = SERVICES.getService(IAService.class);
    // AFormData formData = new AFormData();
    // exportFormData(formData);
    // formData = service.store(formData);
  }
}
```

Why is `execStore()` not called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [Form Lifecycle](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Form#Form_lifecycle) Problem.

Eclipse Scout executes `execStore()` only if at least a value has changed in the form.

To be precise:

- values set during `AbstractFormHandler#execLoad()` are considered as initial values
- values set during `AbstractFormHandler#execPostLoad()` are considered as modified values.

When the user interacts with the form, he is after `PostLoad` event.

To mark the form as modified you can use `IForm#touch()`.

You can change your Unit Test to something like this:

```
AForm form = new AForm();
form.setPersonId(3L);
form.startNew();
Assert.assertEquals("isSaveNeeded [1]", false, form.isSaveNeeded());
form.touch(); // or form.getXyField().setValue(..);
Assert.assertEquals("isSaveNeeded [2]", true, form.isSaveNeeded());
form.doOk();
//assertions on the form.
```

The assertions *"is save needed"* are not necessary. They are only here to illustrate the case.

If `IForm#isSaveNeeded()` returns true, your `execStore()` implementation will be executed.